# How to play live FLV stream?

Tags: live-streaming, flv

I am capturing video from webcam in my PC and in the fly convert it to FLV (using ffmpeg).
As a result I have a continuously growing .FLV file.
And now I would like to play it as a live stream.
I was trying VLC but it plays the file no longer than the duration read from file on initialization.
What player can I use for live playing FLV?
I am working on Ubuntu 16.04.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: You might have to install a server on your hard drive (try XAMPP if available on Linux, i'm PC). In anycase once localhost on your browser shows something you can use FFmpeg to live stream via server/ports to some local link that VLC connects to. There are many tutorials for local streaming. Right now sounds like you're just saving a file and playing it (most players hold a copy of file in memory so ofcos it only holds what it "sampled" when you loaded file, if it changes outside program then VLC doesn't know or care).

Comment: PS: If FFmpeg can detect camera why cant VLC also detect it and just watch the "capture" on VLC (ie: without even saving)? Otherwise you might have to code own tool for sampling x-minutes of video bytes (from HDD) at a time starting at keyframe positions and pass that onto some decoder (depends on programming language) for playback then clear the memory and feed with next chunk (this way can play forever while only holding a few mins in memory at a time).

Comment: Why do you need to use FLV?  If you want to stream, consider a different container format.  If you must use FLV, consider an RTMP server.

Comment: @VC.One 
I have already installed nginx (I have compiled it with enabled module: http_flv_module) - And I was still able to play it with VLC but duration was still limited to the value from initialization.
The fact that I am getting video from camera is just for test purposes.
What I want to achieve is to broadcast LIVE video in FLV format and I am looking for a method how to check if my streaming server is working as expected.

And it is FLV because... yes. I am aware of that there are many more better formats. Though I need to check it with FLV.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot play live FLV directly but there is a tricky protocol popular among Chinese live streaming platform called "http-flv" that would play live flv within http framework.

**Why http-flv?**

1. Latency for HLS / Dash is long. It is about 10 to 20+ seconds.
2. Http-flv reduces end-to-end the latency to **~5 seconds**. It could be played on browsers with MSE support.

**How it works?**

1. FLV is a simple container that "supports" file-based progressive streaming because one could get partial byte range in a flv video and still play it ( for mp4, you would need meta like moov etc for playback. )
2. For file server, host a growing flv file and remove the HTTP response header "content length" so that when client request the file, it does not know the response body size. It would keep the connection and receive videos segments until connection ends.
3. On client side, use flv.js to fetch only the latest segments for a flv file and perform the playback.
4. A lot of other tricks that would make the pipeline work.

There are a lot of source online you could play around with. Here are some references:

1. https://github.com/Bilibili/flv.js/
2. https://github.com/winshining/nginx-http-flv-module
3. A blog about how to achieve this: https://www.yanxurui.cc/posts/server/2017-11-25-http-flv/

Comment: Hi Fei, just happen that we are doing load testing with http-flv protocol based live streaming, wonder if you know how they perform the load testing?

Comment: user2778168 Sry I am not quite familiar with the load testing for http-flv.